# How to create a media query for <canvas>

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I want to create a media query to change the width and height of the canvas tag.

HTML

```
<canvas id="clock" width="250" height="250">
</canvas>
```

I would have expected the width and height attributes to be declared in the usual way. But this doesn't seem to work:

CSS

```
#clock {
    width:250;
    height:250; 
}

@media (max-width: @screen-small) {
    #clock {
        width:200;
        height:200;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing [`<length>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#lengths) values in your rules - use `px` as an example:

```
#clock {
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: @screen-small) {
    #clock {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mjt87/

Comment: how the hell did you manage to write a fiddle and an answer that fast ;D

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a unit. To my knowledge are `width` and `height` attributes in HTML-tags the only place where a lack of units is assumed as number of `px`.

```
#clock {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}
```